# union causing segmentation fault while reading from a file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, unions

I am fairly new to c and am not entirely sure how file manipulation works. I have managed to get this far but I keep running into a segmentation fault and I can figure out how to fix it here is my code:

```
int main() {
    int c;
    char str[50];
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("encrypt.txt", "r+");
    if (file) {
        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF){
                fseek(file, ftell(file)-1, SEEK_SET);
            char d = getc(file);
            union shift sh;
            sh.str = d; //It worked until here
            sh.i = sh.i+5;
            str[c] = sh.str;
            printf("%c", str[ftell(file)-1]);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
}

union shift {
    int i; 
    float f;
    char str;
};
```

I am trying to read from the file ecrypt.txt and use a union to change a char into an int. then it shifts the int by 5 and turns it back into a char, saving it in str

EDIT: I was looking at the first while loop and assumed c was an int. I replaced the c with ftell(file)-1

Comment: What is this even supposed to achieve? What is `str[c]` if `c` is a character from file?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? You never initialise sh.i yet you increment it...

Comment: @AntoineB `sh.i` is set when `sh.d` is, isn't?

Comment: Are you aware that `char` is already an integral type that you can increment directly without accessing it as an `int`?

Comment: `char str[50];` so if `c > 49` you get undefined behaviour. Make it `char str[255];`

Comment: Why are you reading the char twice from the file?

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you want to achieve but look at the declaration of `str`:

```
char str[50];
```

now the assignment of `c`:

```
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF){
```

and then the assignment into `str[c]`

```
    str[c] = completely_irrelevant;
```

if `c > 49` (which is code for `1`) you're accessing `str` out of bounds, which is why you're getting a segmentation fault if your file contains, say, letters which have a code higher than `49`.

To avoid this, make it

```
char str[255];
```

(once that is fixed, you probably have some more work to do on your code, and no, the usage of `union` has nothing to do with the current error)

Comment: thank you this really helped, I was looking at the first use of cand assumed it was an int

Answer (score 0):

The problematic statement is

```
str[c] = sh.str; /* it cause UB if c is greater than 49 */
```

as when you will do `c = getc(file)` what if `c` value is greater than `49` as you declared `str` as array of only `50` character like `char str[50];`. To avoid this declare `str` as

```
char str[255] = ""; /* initialize it */
```

Also when you do `sh.i+5;` what is `sh.i` value ?  you didn't `union` variable. Initialize it like below to avoid undefined behavior.

```
union shift sh = { 0 };
```